# Golang: Multidimensional array using slice of slice strategy resulting in strange output

Tags: multidimensional-array, go, append

I am using following simple code for 2d array in golang, where **APPEND** function is resulting in Duplicate values rather than appending.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
    array := [][]int{}
    row := make([]int, n)
    for _, _ = range row {
        for j, _ := range row {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &row[j])
        }
        fmt.Println("Printing current Row", row)
        array = append(array, row)
        fmt.Println("Printing curent Array", array)
    }
    fmt.Println("Final Array", array)
}
```

But Strangely this are not going unexpectedly.
If suppose i want this thing to happen(input)

```
2
1 2
3 4
```

and i run this program i get this in return

```
2     //Dimension for matrix
1     //Iteration one begins
2
Printing current Row [1 2]
Printing curent Array [[1 2]]
3     //Iteration two begins
4
Printing current Row [3 4]
Printing curent Array [[3 4] [3 4]]
Final Array [[3 4] [3 4]]
```

I am not getting reason that why **APPEND** function is resulting in duplicating entries .
There by want to know how to correct this also underlying **CONCEPT**

Comment: are you sure you copied your code correctly?  When I copy your program to https://play.golang.org/p/mJeZsXlP7r and run it, it produces as output only 'Final Array []' (try it)

Comment: @dmitris are you sure that golang playground allows us to provide input when it runs?

Comment: Never mind, you are right - no stdin in the  Playgroun! :) https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf - "Scanf scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments as determined by the format. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use new slice for each iteration of the first loop, and check for the errors**:

**you read new data to the old same slice**, this is why you have duplicated data.

if you want to use `append` first create array with **zero length** and cap `n`:
 `array := make([][]int, 0, n)`
then change your first loop to: `for i := 0; i < n; i++ {`
and inside this loop make new slice: `row := make([]int, n)`

2 way:
using append (without `fmt.Scan` error checking):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := 0
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    slice := make([][]int, 0, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        row := make([]int, n)
        for j, _ := range row {
            fmt.Scan(&row[j])
        }
        slice = append(slice, row)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

**without using append**  read to `s[i][j]` (with error checking):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var n int
    if m, err := fmt.Scan(&n); m != 1 {
        panic(err)
    }
    s := make([][]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        s[i] = make([]int, n)
        for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
            if m, err := fmt.Scan(&s[i][j]); m != 1 {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

input:

```
2
1 2
3 4
```

output:

```
[[1 2] [3 4]]
```

---

I think this test sample code is clear enough to
show **how slice of slice works** (with commented output):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s1 := [][]int{}
    s2 := []int{1, 2}
    s1 = append(s1, s2)
    fmt.Println(s1) // [[1 2]]

    s2[0], s2[1] = 3, 4
    fmt.Println(s1) // [[3 4]]

    s1 = append(s1, s2)

    fmt.Println(s1) // [[3 4] [3 4]]

    s2[0], s2[1] = 30, 40
    fmt.Println(s1) // [[30 40] [30 40]]

    fmt.Println(len(s2), cap(s2)) // 2 2

    s3 := [][]int{
        []int{1, 2},
        []int{3, 4},
        s2,
        s2,
    }
    fmt.Println(s3) // [[1 2] [3 4] [30 40] [30 40]]
    s2[0] = 100
    fmt.Println(s3) // [[1 2] [3 4] [100 40] [100 40]]
}
```

you created slice of slice `s1` like this :
array [0] =    row[0], row[1]
array [1] =    row[0], row[1]

so when you change row it will seen twice.

Comment: Thanks but want to know why append is behaving so strange that it is appending new row as well as updating others

Comment: @AbhishekSoni: the problem is not the append, you read data to same memory by `fmt.Scanf("%d", &row[j])` for append see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices

Comment: i didn't get because according to me i appended a slice in first iteration to array after that i again pushed the same slice with altered values to  array ,
Now how can during next append it can get same reference for all appended values

Comment: @AbhishekSoni : see new Edit , i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped, what i learned is append function is based on reference and this model is quite different from c++ or java where after pushing the values to array , you can use the same reference variable.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is occurring because you are not adding a new `row` slice to your `array`. Each iteration simply reads into the same `row` slice overriding previous values. Try below:

```
func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
    array := [][]int{}

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        row := make([]int, n) // create a new slice to add next row values
        for j, _ := range row {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &row[j])
        }
        fmt.Println("Printing current Row", row)
        array = append(array, row)
        fmt.Println("Printing curent Array", array)
    }
    fmt.Println("Final Array", array)
}
```

Comment: Really want to know why append function is appending as well as replacing existing data